# Triggering KDE's "Attach as tab to" feature from a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, kde

I very much like the possibility to attach any window to any other one as a tab in KDE. Particularly, as part of my workflow, I often have a Dolphin (file manager) window attached to a Konsole (shell terminal) as depicted below.

Is there a way to achieve this setup via some sort of script? I.e., I'm looking for a way to open the current working directory from the shell in Dolphin and immediately attach it as a tab to the Konsole window.

[image: Konsole tab activated] [image: Dolphin tab activated]